# How to bypass template formatting in Serilog?

Tags: serilog

I would like to insert a simple newline into a Serilog log file without any default template formatting. How can this be done?

I tried creating an additional logger without formatting but it did not seem to work correctly with multiple loggers to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as

```
ILogger _logger // SeriLog interface
_logger.Information("Simple message", null);
```

Does that not work?